# Is there an existing library/plugin to create a dockable, resizable and pinnable sidebar window like those in Visual Studio?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

The solution explorer and toolbox windows in Visual Studio can be made to hide at the side unless they are pinned. They can also be resized. Is there anything that has been able to emulate this behaviour in CSS? I'm hoping someone has already made some jQuery plugin or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how much this control would help you as some of the main functionality are missing. However, please have a look at this link:

http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/examples/AdvancedDocking/#

Comment: Close enough. I should be able to modify it a bit to make it resizeable. Good find. Thanks.